# Sharepoint Ideas help

Tags: custom-form, json, flow, sharepont

It's been a while since I used SharePoint and have now got a chance to improve our SharePoint site it is awful!  It is just random documents all over the place and can't find anything.  My first idea is to start over moving what we have to Archive.

Currently, the setup is a wiki but not on SharePoint it's a word document I want to set up a WiKi and put what's in the document into this.  I have never used Wiki so wonder if there is maybe something better I would ideally think if everything is in one place it will be used better.

knowledge base this is the part I am trying to work as there is a number of ideas I have thought of like to have maybe I am over thinking it?

- Documents should all be set to expire after 1 year.  I have this setup.  But after a year if not updated will be flagged red and email to the owner to update.
- All documents will be PDF so once expired would like to watermark it expired not sure if I can get this to be done?
- Traffic light showing documents green good, amber 3 months till expired and red expired then will move it to retention folder till updated.
- Once document expires will trigger an email to owner group to update or review it
- If a document needs updated anyone can submit a request to update and will email owners to update.  This will then put a note needs reviewed or updated.

I have set flow up so that a request approved or rejected at moment I seem to have it in a loop via outlook when click submit I get the approval again I want it to update in SharePoint?  I am sure I am missing something

We have an awful system at the moment that 3 of us work on an excel spreadsheet then merge to one and compare we do this every 6 months.  We pull a report then check overall to see if we see something wrong 3 of us work on it then merge.  My Idea is to have a master template we then open and then 3 tabs work on then compare the tabs with a formula that will be applied as we work on it to final.

Sorry for all the questions in one I was thinking on more ideas as started to type this.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of questions, I can see you have a lot of plans.  It might be better to break this down in to multiple questions.

Anyway - you'll need to familiarise yourself with Document Libraries, used as a means of structuring files in to 'manageable blocks'.  You've not mentioned whether you have different departments and whether they need their own site (aka Site Collection), but maybe you need to consider the [Information Architecture](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228744/structuring-documents-best-practice/228761#228761) of the site - this link poses a similar sort of question to yours.

You can set Information Management Policy Settings to manage the expiry of aged documents.  For more info on this, please check out this [blog post](https://sharepointmaven.com/set-retention-deletion-policies-files-folders-sharepoint/).

For your Excel spreadsheets - that does sound like an awful, inefficient process.  Just create a Sharepoint List instead, multiple people can work on it.  You can also set 'security' (Permissions) on the List to decide who can modify it and who can only view it.  A list can be customised to create the fields (columns) you need to recreate your spreadsheet.  Plus, if you need it in Excel format at some point, you can use the 'export to Excel' feature to manipulate the data and formatting in Excel!  You can also create a linked, refreshable file.

```
We have a awful system at the moment that 3 of us work on a excel spreadsheet then merge to one and compare we do this every 6 months. We pull a report then check over all to see if we see something wrong 3 of us work on it then merge. My Idea is to have master template we then open and then 3 tabs work on then compare the tabs with formula that will be applied as we work on it to final.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply yeah I started with one idea then got going ad thought might be best to split it myself.  Thanks for your reply some great links to help me with this.

Comment: There are a lot of good blog posts on the SP Maven site, it's worth adding to your favourites.  BTW - I am a reputation points collecting obsessive, if you wouldn't mind you could vote up my answer 8-)